# String com espaços - Regex IsMatch retorna true quando deveria retornar false

Tags: regex, validação

Tenho a seguinte Regex

```
(?=.*\d)(?!.*\s)(?=.*[a-zA-Z\s]).{6,12}
```

Se eu faço testes em site que testam Regex, funciona, na annotation do Model da view para validar funciona, mas quando faço no serviço `regex.IsMatch(" qqq11")` ele retorna `true`, onde deveria trazer `false`.

Comment: Não é mais fácil remover os espaços do início e fim da string antes de validar?

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser alguma diferença entre o como estes sites e a classe Regex funciona.

Fazendo testes aqui alguns sites retornam `true` para este valor, outros retornam `false`, o que você pode tentar fazer é mudar a regex para ele pegar o inicio e fim da linha

```
^(?=.*\d)(?!.*\s)(?=.*[a-zA-Z\s]).{6,12}$
```